# MVC 3 Simple Inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I have come across a situation where the answer should be really straight forward, but it eludes me.

```
public class Note
{

    #region Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int CandidateId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void Save()
    {

    }

    #endregion

}

public class History : Note
{
}
```

As you can see, History inherits Note. They are exactly the same, the only difference between the two is the type Id.

I have this function when getting data from the database

```
    public static Note Parse(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        int TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TypeId"]);
        Note Note;

        if (TypeId == 1)
            Note = new Note();
        else
            Note = new History();

        Note.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]);
        Note.TypeId = TypeId;
        if (dr["ClientId"] != DBNull.Value) Note.ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ClientId"]);
        if (dr["CandidateId"] != DBNull.Value) Note.CandidateId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CandidateId"]);
        Note.DateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateCreated"]);

        Note.UserId = Convert.ToString(dr["UserId"]);
        Note.UserName = Convert.ToString(dr["UserName"]);
        Note.Message = Convert.ToString(dr["Message"]);

        return Note;
    }
```

And then on my MVC page I have this:

```
<ol id="interview-comments">                                
@foreach (Note Note in Model.Notes().OfType<Note>())
{  
}
</ol>

<ol id="history-comments">                             
@foreach (History Note in Model.Notes().OfType<History>())
{  
}
</ol>
```

My question is simple. Is this the correct way to do it?

/r3plica

Comment: Like the answers say, you probably should _not_ do it this way. In general I find that inheritance can bite you, so I tend to stay away from it if possible.

Comment: @jesus.tesh, it's not necessary to "stay away" from inheritance IMHO, but use it only when appropriate. Don't use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail... ;)

Comment: @Lucero - sure, I wasn't claiming inheritance should not be used. Use the right tool for the job, right? :)

Comment: @jesus.tesh, exactly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the whole picture I wouldn't use inheritance here.
You said that Note and History items had different TypeId:s.

Then I would do the following:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Notes().Where(x => x.TypeId == Note.NoteTypeId))
{
}

//and

@foreach(var item in Model.Notes().Where(x => x.TypeId == Note.HistoryTypeId))
{
}

public class Note
{
  public static int HistoryTypeId = 1;
  public static int NoteTypeId = 0;
  /* ... the rest of the implementation */
}
```

You could also change TypeId to an enum and "hide" some of the magic numbers

Edit: 
Depending on the usage you could also implement the check for Historic notes as a property on Note.

```
public class Note
{
  /* ... other properties ... */
  public bool IsHistoric { get { return this.TypeId != 1; } }
}
```

And then the check would simple be

```
@foreach(var note in Model.Notes().Where(x => x.IsHistoric))
{
}

// and

@foreach(var note in Model.Notes().Where(x => !x.IsHistoric())
{
}
```

Comment: yeah, I had something similar in another class with the linq in your first part. I will take your advice and use an Enum for the Types as I don't like using Hard coded Id's and with the Enum I can add as many as I like in the future. Still hard coded, but makes me feel better :D

Answer (score 0):

I might not have the full picture here, but I would consider only using one class - `Note`. And instead have a property on that class - `IsHistoric`. Then make the check based on the property rather than the type.

Answer (score 0):

Since a `History` is a `Note`, your `Model.Notes().OfType<Note>()` will also include the `History` instances - is that on purpose?

You may want to use just one entity and add a flag for whether is is a note or not; that would make it clearer and avoid the inheritance issue.

Or you could use a common interface or abstract base class and not have the classes inherit one from the other, but rather both from the same base, which would fix the `OfType` issue as well.

Or if the inheritance is really correct, then filter like this: `Model.Notes().Where(n => n.GetType()=typeof(Note))`, or just `Model.Notes().Where(n => !(n is History))` - there are many ways to get to Rome.